# Lightweight monitoring for a Windows XP laptop

Tags: monitoring, remote, health, lightweight

I have a windows XP laptop in a remote location. I would like to have an overview for CPU/Memory statistics from a remote location. Monitoring a specific service (a Tomcat instance) would be nice but not essential.

I have seen the monitoring solutions (Nagios, cacti e.t.c) and they are all very heavy. I do not want to install mysql, web server and other stuff like that on the laptop.

I don't even need a web solution at all. It could just be a simple command line app with a server port and on my machine another GUI application would connect there (and not a web browser)

Is there something like this available?

**Answer:**

Perfmon is perfect for my needs

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305610 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.08.pulse.aspx?pr=blog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For monitoring with Nagios etc. you just need a small client on the monitored machine that communicates with the real nagios installation. No database or web server necessary, at least on the clients.

Other options would be built-in performance monitor of Windows (which can be queried remotely) and SNMP (part of the OS, but not installed by default).

Comment: I know that you don't have to install the servers on the laptop. However you have to install them somewhere (This is what I want to avoid). Anyway, your suggestion about remote quering the performance monitor was exactly what I needed!

Comment: -1 for suggesting just what the OP is trying to avoid. 

Lightweight != nagios

Answer (score 0):

One lightweight approach could be to simply use services like logmein or [Teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/index.aspx) to remotely access the machine and check on the service health.

Answer (score 0):

What about something simple like setting up [a perfmon blackbox](http://martin77s.wordpress.com/2010/02/20/perfmon-blackbox/) and zipping/emailng the log files out once a day? You could then analyze the data in perfmon or Excel/etc. on your local system.

It would take a little scripting to stop/email/restart the logging once a day, but it would be fairly simple.